# n.prototype.customizeRequests is not a function at requiring s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using aws s3 to upload zip files. I have created the s3 client object as:

`const client = s3.createClient({ s3Client: awsS3Client })`

But when I run the code, it throws an error and never reaches to this line or anywhere below the require statement for s. i.e: `const s3 = require('s3')` & throws following error:

`{ "errorMessage": "n.prototype.customizeRequests is not a function", "errorType": "TypeError", "stackTrace": [ "TypeError: n.prototype.customizeRequests is not a function", "    at /serverless_sdk/index.js:9:205226", " at Object.<anonymous> (/node_modules/s3/lib/index.js:1:11)" ]}`

**This is happening after updating the NodeJS to any of the versions above version 10.**

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
import { S3 } from 'aws-sdk';
```

or if you use SDK v3 :

```
const { S3Client } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");
const client = new S3Client(clientParams);
```